# Blocks not showing up in my FlappyBird game remake

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate my own version of FlappyBird. You can see my game here: http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2375a22/lab6/lab6.html

The only problem that I've encountered is that none of my "blocks" are showing up. If you have never played FlappyBird, the blocks are objects that you must avoid in order to keep progressing throughout the game. If you touch a block, you lose.

My player controls are working and the collision system seems to be fine as well. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```js
 $(function () {

 alert("Welcome to Space Dodge!" 
  + "\n\nNavigate your vessel through the unknown for as long as you can!"
  + "\n\nUse 'Spacebar' to control the ship."
  + "\n\nIf the ship hits a block, the top, or the bottom, you lose!")

 //Game variables
 var game_area = $('#game_area');
    var ship = $('#ship');
    var block = $('.block');
    var block1 = $('#block1');
    var block2 = $('#block2');
    var score = $('#score');
    var restart_button = $('#restart_button');

    //Set up variables
    var game_width = parseInt(game_area.width());
    var game_height = parseInt(game_area.height());
    var block_initial_position = parseInt(block.css('right'));
    var block_initial_height = parseInt(block.css('height'));
    var ship_left = parseInt(ship.css('left'));
    var ship_height = parseInt(ship.height());

    //Starting speed - this will increase by +1 every time the player goes through a checkpoint
    var speed = 10;

    var go_up = false;
    var update_score = false;
    var game_over = false;

    var the_game = setInterval(function () {

        if (collision(ship, block1) || collision(ship, block2) || parseInt(ship.css('top')) <= 0 || parseInt(ship.css('top')) > game_height - ship_height) {

            end_game();
            alert("Game Over! \n\nClick 'Restart' to play again. ")

        } else {

            var block_current_position = parseInt(block.css('right'));

            //Update the score when the poles have passed the bird successfully
            if (block_current_position > game_width - ship_left) {
                if (score_updated === false) {
                    score.text(parseInt(score.text()) + 1);
                    score_updated = true;
                }
            }

            //Check whether the poles went out of the container
            if (block_current_position > game_width) {
                var new_height = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);

                //Change the pole's height
                block1.css('height', block_initial_height + new_height);
                block2.css('height', block_initial_height - new_height);

                //Increase speed,
                speed = speed + 1;
                score_updated = false;
                pole_current_position = pole_initial_position;
            }

            //Move blocks
            block.css('right', block_current_position + speed);

            if (go_up === false) {
                go_down();
            }
        }

    }, 40);

    //Determine collison domains
    function collision($div1, $div2) {
     
     //First set of axis
        var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
        var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
        var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
        var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
        var b1 = y1 + h1;
        var r1 = x1 + w1;

        //Second set of axis
        var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
        var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
        var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
        var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
        var b2 = y2 + h2;
        var r2 = x2 + w2;

        // If the ship meets this condition, collision is false
        if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
        return true;
    }

    function go_down() {
        ship.css('top', parseInt(ship.css('top')) + 5);
    }

    function up() {
        ship.css('top', parseInt(ship.css('top')) - 10);
    }

    function end_game() {
        clearInterval(the_game);
        game_over = true;
    }

     $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key === 32 && go_up === false && game_over === false) {
            go_up = setInterval(up, 50);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key === 32) {
            clearInterval(go_up);
            go_up = false;
        }
    });

    //Reload the page and reset the game
    restart_button.click(function () {
        location.reload();
    });

});
```

```css
 body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
    }

    #game_area {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid chartreuse;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    #ship {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('ship.png');
    height: 42px;
    width: 65px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
    }

    .block {
    position: absolute;
    height: 130px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    right: -50px;
    }

    #block1 {
    top: 0;
    }

    #block2 {
    bottom: 0;
    }
    
    #score_area {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: chartreuse;
    }
```

```html
<body>
 <!-- Game area on the page -->
 <div class="container" id="game_area">
  <div id="ship"></div>
  <div id="block1"></div>
  <div id="block2"></div>
 </div>

 <!-- Score section -->
 <div class="container" id="score_area">
  <P>Score: <span id="score">0</span></P>
 </div>

 <!-- Restart button -->
 <div class="container" id="restart_area">
 <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
    id="restart_button">Restart</button></center>
    </div>

    <!-- Game script -->
    <script src="lab6_game.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class block to... blocks :p

```
    <div id="block1" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block2" class="block"></div>
```

Instead of

```
    <div id="block1" ></div>
    <div id="block2" ></div>
```